# Retrieve 2FA form paypal on selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, paypal

i have try to pay with paypal with selenium, so i have this:

```
    password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='password']")
    password.send_keys("password")
    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='btnLogin']")
    action = ActionChains(browser)
    action.click(on_element = element)
    action.perform()
```

but after i have a issue i have to retrieve the 2FA code from an authentificator app and i don't know how to do this, i'm on mac.
Is there a solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution
it's to create this function

```
def top():
key = "XXXXXXXXX"
totp = TOTP(key)
token = totp.now()
return token
```

and after you set this for paypal with selenium

```
password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='otpCode']")
            password.send_keys(top())
```